# Could not stream from XboxOne, Please try again later (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, xbox-one

I recently acquired Windows 10 and I'm having issue's streaming from the XboxOne to my Windows 10 pc.

This worked for the first time for 10 minutes a couple of days ago but now it seems to have stopped working.

The message returned is always the same.

> Could not stream from XboxOne, Please try again later.

[image: Image attached]

I have tried various techniques to get it working but to no avail.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which version of the Xbox app are you using?

Comment: It's 11.11.1901200000

Comment: I've gotten this recently too. Tried everything and can't seem to get it working again. Used to work flawlessly for awhile, it hasn't worked for me since the latest Xbox One update.